# Filter realtime Tweets with tweepy -Parameters

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

i’m trying to get tweets with [tweepy](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html#tweepy-api-twitter-api-wrapper), filtered by the following parameters:

```
filter(follow=None, track=None, is_async=False, locations=None, stall_warnings=False, languages=None, encoding=‘utf8’, filter_level=None)
```

i have a very specific problem and i cant find any solution.Filter handles parameters with logical OR as i read here :

> " Bounding boxes do not act as filters for other filter parameters.
>
> For example `track=twitter&locations=-122.75,36.8,-121.75,37.8` would
>   match any Tweets containing the term Twitter (even non-geo Tweets) OR
>   coming from the San Francisco area."

I’d like to know if there is any way(or any library except tweepy) to filter  **with AND between parameters**  ,not OR.

For example i want a batch of tweets in english language AND location=-122.75,36.8,-121.75,37.8,not either of them.
Thanks

Comment: Two things. No this is not possible with the free API (you can achieve this with commercial API s); secondly only about 1-2% of Tweets have location data attached so do not assume there is a dataset here.

Comment: Ok thank you very much.With commercial API you mean the Enterprice category?